# Any way to "warm start" Android voice recognition?

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I've got voice recognition running in my Android app.  However, the user experience is poor due to the lag when the Google voice recognition dialog is launched.  The app relies on receiving a response from the user after a prompt, but when the RecognizerIntent is started, it takes a couple of seconds before the user can actually provide his/her response.  It doesn't feel 'natural' enough.

What I'd like to find out is if anyone knows a way to sort of 'warm start' the recognizer activity so that it is ready immediately following my prompt.

I'm happy to provide more details if it would be helpful.